# Arc menu item style like in tumblr app for Android

Tags: android-layout, android, android-custom-view, android-menu

I tweaked https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu library to make it work from my purpose and that is working fine. Is there anyway I can build a menu like as in tumblr app or is it possible by tweaking the ArcMenu project or https://github.com/siyamed/android-satellite-menu ? I have doubts on the mathematical functions to be applied to create the style.

I am looking for a animation similar to tumblr app's animation.

[image]

Comment: The android app has a right starting menu and it doesn't have any animations(except for the actual menu button and the rolling text). If this is what you want it's simple to make. If the iOs app has a different behavior you should explain it(either images or words).

Comment: @Luksprog I need exact replica of how tumblr menu works along with animation

Comment: @parag Yes. I have customized ArcMenu project.

Comment: @intrepidkarthi hi, if you have already achieved these menus can you help me out by sharing it, if you don't mind as you said you will be uploading the code.

Comment: @intrepidkarthi waiting for your reply.

Comment: @intrepidkarthi have you created this kind of menu?

Comment: @ShashankAgarwal yes. It is tweaked from RayMenu with changes on the coordinates based on the device size. I will post in github when I have time

Comment: @intrepidkarthi  Please post it , i need it badly.

Comment: From which app you have get this screen, As tumbler does not have this animation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use , [Arc Menu](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu)

implement RayMenu and modify [RayLayout](https://github.com/daCapricorn/ArcMenu/blob/master/library/src/com/capricorn/RayLayout.java)

and modify the `private static Animation`createExpandAnimation()` method with your specific coordinate.

Comment: can you tell me the way to apply animation?

Comment: check the 119 line in the RayLayout

Comment: any result for your problem men, please tel me if it work for you

Comment: i will implement an exemple for you this wekend :)

Comment: sorry not yet , i haven't time

Comment: I have done it. It works. I will update the code once after making it perfect. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @intrepidkarthi could you say how you achieved it. I have looked at the line as indicated in the comment but nothing seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways I do this in iOS. In iOS we have Views similar to that of Android and we can specify coordinates (frame of view) to place them in their superview.

Assumptions :

1)Assume you have a locus i.e circle with equation x^2 + y^2 = c
( Hint : All views are on this locus i.e center of all views coincide with this circle)

2) You need select a value of C depending on the curve you need and initial point which is 
(0,HEIGHT_OF_SCREEN) as stating point for placing views.

[image]

Algorithm :

```
int angularDisplacementBetweenEachView = 10; // distance between two views in radians 
// coordinates of X button in your screen
int startPositionOfViewX = 0;
int startPositionOfViewY = HEIGHT_OF_SCREEN;
// constant to decide curve
int C = 125;
```

-(void) main (){ // this is generally done in view controller

```
for(int i = 1; i< menu_items.count; i++){
    Rect position = getCoordinatesForView(menu_item.get(i),menu_item.get(i-1).rect.x,menu_item.get(i-1).rect.y);
    addView(menu_item.get(i),position.x,position.y); 
}
```

}

// method returns the coordinates (x,y) at which the view is required to be 
//placed.
-(Rect)getCoordinatesForView(View currentView, int prevViewX, int prevViewY){

// convert to polar cordinates
   // refer diagram

// this is also the radius of the virtual circle
   float r = sqrt(pow(x,2),pow(y,2)); 
   float theta = atan(y,x);

//r & theta are polar coordinates of previous menu item
   float theta2 = (angularDisplacementBetweenEachView + r*theta)/r;

// convert back to cartesian coordinates
   int x2 = r * cos (theta);
   int y2 = r * sin (theta);

return new rect(x2,y2);
}

Comment: @kunal Balani , in ios you have a fixed width and height of scrren ,but in android we have multi screen and density it's not the same.

Comment: @Saklos this should not matter. in iOS too we have multiple screens for iPhone 4 and iphone 5. This algorithm is not dependent of screen size at all.

Comment: thank you for your informations, we have (Android) canvas and paint

Comment: You don't need custom drawing here. Canvas and paint is for that. My code just tells you where to position your views. You need to implement this in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

try this for Arc menu. u can use this sattelite menu 
https://github.com/ketanpatel25/android-satellite-menu-center